¿Cómo determinar el número óptimo de clusters en un algoritmo de clustering?
Estoy estudiando inteligencia artificial y actualmente estoy en el tema de clustering. Me llamó la atención la importancia de elegir el número correcto de clusters para obtener buenos resultados en los algoritmos de clustering, como k-means.
Lo que he entendido hasta ahora es que debo probar con distintos parámetros hasta encontrar el que me de mejores resultados, pero no entiendo como puede eso ser eficiente.
Mi pregunta es si hay otros criterios o enfoques útiles, especialmente cuando se trabaja con datos de alta dimensionalidad o estructuras complejas y qué consideraciones adicionales se deben tener en cuenta al seleccionar el número de clusters en el contexto de inteligencia artificial y aprendizaje automático.
Agradecería mucho cualquier explicación acerca del tema.

No hay una fórmula exacta para establecer el número de clusters, es una decisión bien abierta. En aprendizaje no supervisado, dependerá del número de clases que quieras obtener. Si bien no existe una fórmula exacta, sí hay dos métodos muy utilizados que te permitirán tomar esta decisión, estos son el método del Codo (Elbow en inglés) y el valor de la métrica de Silhouette.
El primero es una aproximación pragmática, en la cual evalúas gráficamente la suma de la distancia de cada punto al centroide de su cluster. Cuando al aumentar los clusters, esta suma no se reduce a la misma tasa, ya el hecho de agregar más clusters no aporta en la reducción de la distancia (o sea, siempre aportará, pero no de forma importante). En este punto, se forma un codo en la gráfica y es ahí donde se establece el número de clusters:

Imagen tomada de builtin.com
Puedes encontrar casos donde el codo sea difuso y no tengas claridad para tomar esta decisión:

Para estos casos, se utiliza la métrica de Silhouette. Esta métrica mide cuán similar es un punto a su cluster en comparación con otros clusters. Su rango es de -1 a 1 y mientras más cercano a 1, mejor es la definición del número de clusters. De igual modo, la puedes graficar:

En este caso, 5 clusters es el valor más apropiado para clasificar el set de datos de prueba.
Para reproducir este resultado, ejecuta el sgte código:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
b = np.random.normal(1, 1, 1000)
c = np.random.normal(2, 1, 1000)
d = np.random.normal(3, 1, 1000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d})

sse = {}

for k in range(1, 10):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state = 1).fit(df)
    sse[k] = kmeans.inertia_

plt.figure()
plt.plot(list(sse.keys()), list(sse.values()), 'bx-')
plt.xlabel("Número de clusters")
plt.ylabel("SSE")
plt.show()

sc = {} 

for k in range(2, 10):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state = 1).fit(df)
    labels = kmeans.predict(df)
    sc[k] = silhouette_score(df, labels)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(list(sc.keys()), list(sc.values()), 'bx-')
plt.xlabel("Número de clusters")
plt.ylabel("Valor de Silhouette")
plt.show()


Si el clustering se usa para conocer la estructura de una población, establecer a priori el número de grupos es un contrasentido. Con algoritmos como K-medias, la solución es ejecutarlo unas cuantas veces, como indica @aldo_tapia, y usar una métrica que te permita determinar K. Pero así se pierde la eficiencia del algoritmo K-medias (o cualquier otro en el que se determine el número de grupos a priori).
Ahora bien, hay algoritmos menos eficientes (pero más que repetir uno varias veces) que ayudan a determinar el número óptimo de grupos. Por ejemplo el clustering jerárquico (AgglomerativeClustering) produce una estructura conocida como "linkage" que puede representarse en forma de "dedrograma", y cuyo análisis permite determinar el número óptimo de grupos.

Un criterio simple puede ser establecer una distancia mínima entre grupos. Se busca esa distancia en el eje y, y se traza una línea horizontal que corta el árbol en varias ramas, cada una de las cuales forma un grupo.
Otro criterio más elaborado es el de Ward, que busca minimizar la varianza intra-grupos mientras se maximiza la varianza inter-grupos.
Eso sí, el clustering jerárquico tiene sus sutilezas. Por ejemplo, es necesario definir dos métricas, la distancia entre elementos individuales (metric) y la distancia entre grupos (linkage). Según se elijan, los resultados son muy diferentes.

